# php replace special character from the variable value

Tags: php

I have a variable

$school_name;

It's fetching many data from the server and I want to replace **comma**, **underscore** and **dash** to the variable value and echo
but **the problem is I can't replace it**
Please support for fix the bug
Thank you

Comment: Please share us the code you have tried.

Comment: @pupil I just fetching data using php 7 and mysqli . Here is variable to fetch all school names. **E.G 1:**  _Raichand_International....school_. **E.G 2:** Latin_Girls__School** Now I want to replace **comma* and **underscore**

Comment: replace the comma and underscores with which character? your question made it sound like you wanted to replace them with your $school_name var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use str_replace function.

```
<?php
$result = "GOOD_AFTERNOON-TODAY,FINE";
$shool_name = "test";

$result = str_replace(array(',','-','_'), $shool_name, $result );
echo $result;
?>
```

**output**

```
GOODtestAFTERNOONtestTODAYtestFINE
```

**Check in Editor: [Click Here](https://eval.in/553882)**

**For AND replace with &.**

```
<?php
$result = "Raichand_International..and..school";
$shool_name = "&";

$result = str_replace(array('and'), $shool_name, $result );
echo $result;
?>
```

**output**

```
Raich&_International..&..school
```

Comment: It's working but the is a other problem .  **E.G 1: Raichand_International..and..school** I want to replace **and** to **&** . I was successfully replaced **and** but I can't echo **&**

Comment: Also preg_replace() useful to you.

Comment: can you write demo ?

Comment: I have written it in online editor you can check there. Click here. eval.in/553897 @GourabMazumder

Answer (score 3):

Use str_replace like this

```
$result = str_replace(array(',','-','_'), $shool_name, $yourStringFromServer);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str_replace(array(',','_','-'), $shool_name, $result);
```